# How to fail a jenkins job based on a condition

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I use Jmeter to validate functional test for our API's. I have created an HTML file which contains the total number of tests executed and the passing/failure ones. This is a customized report.

Can I set a condition such that the build fails if there is a single failure in the report?

Please not that I have already tried performance plugin. But my assertion here is to see if the test case fails or passes and not the reponse/throughtput time.

Not sure if there is a plugin which will enable me to read the HTML and then fail the report if it sees a failing test case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest option would be running your JMeter test using [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool as a wrapper. Taurus has powerful and flexible [Pass/Fail Criteria](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-your-load-tests-with-pass-fail-criteria-a-guide) subsystem where you can configure any combination of test failure thresholds and if any failure occurs - Taurus will exit with non-zero [exit status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status). Jenkins is smart enough to catch this non-zero exit code and fail the build.

JMeter-only solution will be adding a [JSR223 Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) with the script like:

```
if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
    System.exit(1)
}
```

Which is basically doing the same - in case of any failure the test will immediately exit with status of `1` triggering the build failure.

Answer (score 3):

You could just use a shell job, grep for the failures and exit if found, something like this :

```
#!/bin/sh
if grep 'failure' file.html; then
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the structure of your HTML file, but since it's a test pass / fail report then I suppose it's pretty simple.
You may try adding "Execute Python script" (needs "Python plugin") to the job. With that you can easily parse HTML doc and check the results using a simple script.

Comment: Yes, it has a column for the status which marks TRUE/FALSE the result. Is there a specimen which i can refer to ?

Comment: Sorry, don't have any example right now. You can look up HTML parsing examples at Python Docs pages or check out examples for Python HTML parser library BeautifulSoup. 
If your failed tests are marked in your table by FAIL or FALSE, then I think you could skip the parsing and just grep the whole file like @cheseaux suggested in next answer

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with Jenkins and JMeter.  Here's what I did:

1. Install this plugin: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin
2. for your logParserfile, add this:

> error /FAILED/

3. Create a BeanShell Assertion for each sampler you are testing that contains something like this:

   String testscenario = "TEST SCENARIO: ";
   String requestName = "getRequest";
   String ver = "${My_ver}";
   String respData = new String(ResponseData);

   if (respData.contains("OK"))
   {
       log.info(testscenario+"Passed. "+requestName+" version ="+ver); 
       print(testscenario+"Passed. "+requestName+" version ="+ver);
   } else 
   {
       log.error(testscenario+"*FAILED. "+requestName);
       print(testscenario+"*FAILED. "+requestName);
   }

When your Jenkins job runs and anything fails, the FAILED log entry will show